# S3 Creation CloudFormation results in 400 Bad Request

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have this problem when creating S3 bucket using CloudFormation. I get a 400 Bad request. Would appreciate if anyone can help.

> `aws cloudformation deploy --profile DEV --stack-name testBucket --template-file create_bucket.yml --region us-east-1 --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --parameter-overrides BucketName=myBucket`

Template:

```yaml
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
    Parameters:
      BucketName:
        Description: Provisioned read throughput for each table
        Type: String
    Resources:
      MYBUCKET:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          BucketName: ${BucketName}
      MYBUCKETPOLICY:
        Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
        Properties:
          Bucket: !Ref MYBUCKET
          PolicyDocument:
            Id: ReportPolicy
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Sid: ReportBucketPolicyDoc
                Effect: Allow
                Action: "s3:*"
                Principal:
                  AWS: !Join ['', ["arn:aws:iam::", !Ref "AWS::AccountId", ":root"]]
                Resource: !Join ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref MYBUCKET, '/*']]
```

Error

> Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad
>   Request; Request ID: B4AEAA3C454B7868; S3 Extended Request ID:
>   ATFscTA4dQw8J8AYUfkIARYhiT4/BpVWRcD172WnR75Uzm+i5dlHOTC2HCb9drkO16dzYiELJZc=)

Answer (score 21):

The following thread is relevant for anyone trying to change the region of an S3 bucket *just after* they have deleted a bucket in another region.

Essentially there's a delay between a bucket being deleted in one region and the name being available in all other regions. So if you deleted a bucket in `ap-southeast-2` and then tried to create a bucket with the same name is `us-east-1` you should expect to receive this kind of error.

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6646#issuecomment-597905903

Comment: you are a lifesaver, thank you! Amazon _seriously_ needs to improve their messaging on this error.

Comment: @Rabadash8820 agreed, this possibly saved hours of debugging.

Answer (score 9):

You should be using `!Ref BucketName` instead of `${BucketName}`

```yaml
  MYBUCKET:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
```

Comment: How did you get this? I mean is there a way to get info about such case of errors e.g. cloudtrail or smthg like that?

Comment: This answer helped me locate a mistake of mine, where I lacked the dollar-sign in `Fn::Sub: "${BucketName}"`, resulting in `Fn::Sub: "{BucketName}"` and a similar 400 error. Even the cfn-lint tool only reports this as a warning, sadly.

Comment: This is wrong, BucketName is a variable and should be used with !Sub ${BucketName}

Comment: @Baris This is _not_ wrong. You can access Parameters in any of the following ways: `!Ref BucketName`, `!Sub "${BucketName}"`, `Fn::Ref: BucketName`, `Fn::Sub "${BucketName}"`, and others depending on how verbose you want to get with the intrinsic functions and quotes...

Comment: @VladyslavNikolaiev I'd recommend cfn-lint, and if you're using VSCode, there are plugins that leverage this.

Answer (score 1):

You did not reference the `BucketName` parameter correctly:

```
MYBUCKET:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
    BucketName: !Sub ${BucketName}  # Or !Ref BucketName
```