# How to use variables in bucket names AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a Cloudformation template that creates an S3 bucket. I want to configure it so that the bucket is named using one of the parameters passed into the template. I am able to substitute the param in other places in the template, but the bucket creation fails when I try and sub it in here.

```yaml
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub '${STRING_PARAM}-example-bucketname'
```

This gives a `Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request` when the cloudformation stack is created. I've tried hard coding in the name which has worked, so I'm pretty sure it's a valid S3 bucket name.

Per [S3 Creation CloudFormation results in 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292997/s3-creation-cloudformation-results-in-400-bad-request/54558937#54558937) referring (`! Ref` instead of `! Sub`) to the param/resource directly works, but I'm thinking I should be able to sub the param in here like everywhere else.

Comment: Hi! Please post a complete template so we can reproduce the error. Also, your question title is "How to use wildcard bucket names" but you don't mention wildcards in the question?

Comment: Fails how? Are you sure that's a valid bucket name?

Comment: @kichik see edits

Comment: Is there a more descriptive error in the stack events tab?

Comment: @kichik Unfortunately no, but have seen others online with the same so relatively confident that kind of variable sub is not allowed there, but I don't know _why_ that isn't i.e. if there is a more 'correct' way to do it. I think I can create my own custom resource and reference that, but it seems strange that I can't just use the param to create a string name.

Comment: When trying this template out (it's incomplete so I had to guess `STRING_PARAM` is a parameter) I get `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template format error: Parameter name STRING_PARAM is non alphanumeric.`

Comment: Can you provide `STRING_PARAM` definition in your template?

Answer (score 0):

Your value for `BucketName` is fine.  This is the correct syntax for using `!Sub` and should work.

The problem is that the names of parameters must be alpha numeric so `STRING_PARAM` is invalid since it has an underscore character in it.

Update your parameter name to be something like `StringParam` and it should get you past the `Parameter name STRING_PARAM is non alphanumeric.` error message.

Comment: i tried the below 
```BucketName: !Sub kna-de-${EnvironmentName}-airflow-${Airflowversion}``` and i'm providing the values of EnvironmentName and Airflowversion through a json version  --parameter-overrides $(jq -r '.[] | [.ParameterKey, .ParameterValue] | "\(.[0])=\(.[1])"' env/kna-vpc.json) --no-execute-changeset
  {
    "ParameterKey": "EnvironmentName",
    "ParameterValue": "sandbox"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Airflowversion",
    "ParameterValue": "2.0.2"
  }
it errors out Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [Airflowversion, EnvironmentName].Pls help.